# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise) nb-card-header' is not a known element:

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-admin

I'm quite new to NGX-Template and Angular. I'm making my way forwards, but got stuck on a issue.

I've created a new page: customer. In this page I want to render a nb-card element

```
  <div *ngFor="let customer of values" class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xxxl-6">
    <nb-card>
        <nb-card-header>{{customer.name}}</nb-card-header>
          <nb-card-body>
            <p>Beautifull body</p>
          </nb-card-body>
        <nb-card-footer>Good customer</nb-card-footer>
        </nb-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my customer module I've imported the theme and nbcardmodule

```
import { ThemeModule } from '../../@theme/theme.module';
import {
  NbButtonModule,
  NbCardModule,
  NbProgressBarModule,
  NbTabsetModule,
  NbUserModule,
  NbIconModule,
  NbSelectModule,
  NbListModule,
} from '@nebular/theme';
import { CustomerRoutingModule } from './customer-routing.module';
import { CustomerCardComponent } from './customer-card/customer-card.component';
import {CustomerComponent } from './customer.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NbButtonModule,
    NbCardModule,
    NbProgressBarModule,
    NbTabsetModule,
    NbUserModule,
    NbIconModule,
    NbSelectModule,
    NbListModule,
    ThemeModule,
    CustomerRoutingModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    CustomerCardComponent, CustomerComponent  ],

})
export class CustomerModule {}
```

Than finaly my customer.component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Customer } from '../../@core/models/customer.model';
import { CustomerService } from '../../@core/services/customer.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-customer',
  templateUrl: './customer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer.component.scss']
})
export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {

  public message: string;
  public values: any[];

  constructor(private customerService: CustomerService){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.customerService.getAll<Customer[]>().subscribe((data: Customer[]) => this.values = data, error => () => {
      this.message = 'Error: Could not get the data from the service';
    },
    () => {
      this.message = 'succes';
    });

  }
}
```

This is the error supplied by the console

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
'nb-card-header' is not a known element:
1. If 'nb-card-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'nb-card-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("  <div *ngFor="let customer of values" class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xxxl-6">
    <nb-card>
        [ERROR ->]<nb-card-header>{{customer.name}}</nb-card-header>
          <nb-card-body>
            <p>Beautifull"): ng:///PagesModule/CustomerComponent.html@3:8
```

So I hope someone can push me in the right direction. I'm sure it's a little thing what I'm overlooking.

Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: can you share your code on https://stackblitz.com ?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind... I've declared my Customer component in my pages.module. So it was declared double (see above Customer.Module.ts).

I've deleted the customer.module and things are working.